# Laravel Migration Type Year become undefined Method

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

I have a problem with my migration on laravel 5.8. I am tring to make Year Column as mentioned in documentation. But I keep on getting this error "**[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::year()**".

This is my migration file :

```
Schema::create('pengajuan_arsip', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('uuid');
        $table->integer('id_pegawai_pengaju');
        $table->string('nip_pengaju',50);
        $table->string('nik_pengaju',50);
        $table->string('nama_pengaju',200);
        $table->string('bidang',100);
        $table->string('sub_bidang',100);
        $table->string('tingkat',50);
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->boolean('is_setuju');
        $table->integer('setuju_kasi_by');
        $table->year('tahun_mulai');
        $table->year('tahun_akhir');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('detail_histori_arsip', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('uuid');
        $table->integer('id_pengajuan_arsip');
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->integer('status_by');
        $table->integer('diambil_by');
        $table->date('tanggal_diambil');
        $table->integer('id_ruang_arsip');
        $table->date('tanggal_pindah');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('detail_arsip', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('uuid');
        $table->integer('id_pengajuan_arsip');
        $table->string('nama_dokumen',200);
        $table->year('tahun_dokumen');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: What database driver are you using?

Comment: You might wanna check your laravel version. Older versions doesn't have year() method on Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.8 and PostgreSQL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest utilizing an unsigned small integer instead. There is nothing truly remarkable about a year value that would require its own special database column type:

```
$table->unsignedSmallInteger('tahun_mulai');
$table->unsignedSmallInteger('tahun_akhir');
```

This will allow you to save values from `0`  to `65535`.

If for whatever reason you need B.C. times represented by a negative number, then try with a signed small integer:

```
$table->smallInteger('tahun_mulai');
$table->smallInteger('tahun_akhir');
```

This will allow you to save values from `-32768` to `32767`

Comment: thank you. this is make me crazy so i follow your alternative way n works perfectly.